# White/translucent-worms what to do?

Tags: worms

I found White/translucent-worms and I want to know what they are, how to take care of them and do they produce on their own?

Comment: Can you snap a picture and put it into your question.  I"m sure there are a plethora of translucent worms.  I've also learned recently to put your location.  That can help them to isolate your issue potentially.

Comment: As noted, we'll need a photo, a description of where you found these worms, and how they're affecting your plants. Questions about identifying animals are off topic here unless they are related to pest damage.

Comment: I'd still guess some sort of beetle.